# Road map in algebra after Jacabson's Basic algebra I-II

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I believe that there is someone who can answer my question on a platform like Mathoverflow, which has many experienced mathematicians. As you know, there is usually a hierarchy between mathematical texts. For example Dummit algebra <Lang algebra <Jacabson's basic algebra I-II <......... In this hierarchical chain, after Jacabson's Basic Algebra I-II, I would like to ask if there are any books, monographs, notes or comprehensive reference works in general algebra or in the following sub-branches of algebra that you can recommend for further material (examples of reference works are the 7000 page stack project in algebraic geometry or Jacob Lurie's 2000 page Kerodon project in homotopy theory).

By sub-branches of algebra I mean Linear algebra , Lie theory ,Group theory , Representation theory ,Ring theory, Commutative algebra ,Field theory , Homological algebra ,Module theory , Category theory Galois theory

Comment: The further reading list (bibliography) may be a good source to consult. I do not know if your textbook provides further reading list, but I know Hungerford's *Algebra* (GTM$73$) and Grillet's *Abstract Algebra* (GTM$242$) both does.

Comment: @Asigan In my opinion, after Nathan Jacobson's Basic Algebra I-II books, it is unlikely that you will need the material contained in these books. But thank you for sharing your opinion

Comment: I did not mean the text of the two books, but the further-reading list at the end of the books, which might contain good books on following subjects.

Comment: @Asigan But since the books were written between the early 1970s and the late 1980s, the references are generally old. I'm looking for more updated, organized and comprehensive books.